# Json data comes with backslash and not able to set accept media type

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core-webapi

Hi I am facing issue in setting up (Accept : "application/vnd.api+json") in header and my json result returns backslash (picture attached)

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class project : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public project(IConfiguration configuration, HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        try
        {

        // Set the API key in the request headers
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _configuration["ApiSettings:ApiKey"]);

        var content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var authResponse = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://www.example.com/auth", content);

        if (!authResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return BadRequest("Not found");
        }
        // Parse the initial response content
        var authToken = await authResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);
        
        var url = "https://www.example.com/api/credential/";
        var personCredentials = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            return Ok(await personCredentials.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());


            
        } catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            string errorMessage = $"Error making API call: {ex.Message}";
            return StatusCode((int)ex.StatusCode, errorMessage);
        }

    }
}
```

I am using jsonplaceholder api to show the result output. The api I will be using header with token and (Accept : "application/vnd.api+json"). I tried adding this but it gave me media not support error.
[image: api result output]

If any one can help me here would great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is a double encoded json string, this happens because you read the data as string and return it as json (see the [ControllerBase.Ok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.ok?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controllerbase-ok(system-object)) method signature, it accepts `object` and will result in serialization of the value). You need either deserialize the string and pass it to `Ok` or try to return content result directly. For example:

```cs
return Content(await personCredentials.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Comment: This work for me thanks. any help with header would appreciate I am getting Unsupported media type "errors": [
    {
      "code": "unknownrepresentation.error",
      "description": "Unknown representation error",
      "message": "Unsupported media type 'application/vnd.api+json' for resource 'alternative-credential-types'"
    }

Comment: I was calling wrong api which does not support that mediatype. now it is fix Thank you!