# Why is .NET 6 minimal API returning JSON as a string and not as JSON?

Tags: c#, json, string, .net-core, minimal-apis

I have a minimal API in .NET 6. In this API, I call a 3rd party API which returns normal json formatted data by using this code:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    jsonResponse = await response.Contet.ReadAsStringAsync
}
```

`jsonResponse` looks like this for example:

```
{
    "response":
    {
        "AnArray": [
                      "Id": 11,
                      "AnotherId":22
                   ],
        "AndACityArray": [
                             "New York",
                             "London",
                             "Berlin"
                         ],
       "ADirectionArray": [
                             "North",
                             "East",
                             "South",
                             "West"
                          ]
    }
}
```

If I return this as it is, in postman it is escaped like

```
{\"response\": and so on}
```

If I replace the escape chars it looks good, but its still plain text.

I tried to return it as it is. I tried `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to dynamic or to object. In this case, it is returned as JSON, but there are just empty arrays.

```
{response:[
  [
    []
  ],
  [
    []
  ],
  [
    []
  ],
}
```

The structure of that JSON can change, so I can't just define a class to deserialize it.

I tried different results. `Results.Text`, `Results.JSON`, converted it back and forwards.

I just want to pass the json data I get from the 3rd party API, straight through my minimal API and return it.

Comment: Json is a string if it is not a javascript object. What is the problem? Can you post the code you have tried and what is not workong properly?

Comment: @Serge the problem is, that the data is returned as string and not as JSON

Comment: It is supposed to return a string. This is why it is used over the network.

Comment: I want to return JSON, if I return a string the user of the api have to JSON.Parse the data they get in JavaScript

Comment: JSON **IS** strings. That's all it is: a particular way of arranging data **in a string** so it will be consistent and understandable on the other end.

Comment: Side note: sample text shown in the question is *not* JSON. I'm somewhat surprised it does not immediately fail to deserialize... You may want to re-read the [mre] guidance and fix up both code and sample "JSON" in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to return a string which will be encoded as json (hence the resulting double encoded json string), use [`Results.Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results.content?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

```cs
return Results.Content(jsonResponse);
```

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` does not work because Minimal APIs use `System.Text.Json`, not `Newtonsoft.Json` (where `JsonConvert` comes from), so the underlying dynamic object created by it seems not being processed correctly. If you want to stick with serialize-deserialize approach you should look into corresponding `System.Text.Json` APIs (like [`JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-7-0#use-jsonnode) or `JsonDocument`, also note that sample JSON is not a valid one, so if it is actually your JSON and not a typo, then you will need to fix it first). But I would argue that the content approach is better choice here.

Comment: You Sir, have saved my night. Results.Content(jsonResponse, contentType: "application/json") solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @John you just doing a double job. It was converted to json string, now you have deserialized it to object, and after this the object was converted to a json string again by API action response.

Comment: @Serge there is no double job in `Results.Content` approach.

Comment: @GuruStron I am sorry, but it is your opinion, that is my opinion. I don't belive that iResults.Content(jsonResponse, contentType: "application/json") sends a binary object

Comment: @Serge TBH I don't understand what is opinionated here? `Results.Content` just writes the content string to the HTTP response, there is no deserialization-serialization happening.

Comment: @GuruStron IMHO ,  you can use return Ok(json) or return  new JsonResult(json) or just return json (if your action returns string) the result still will be the same.

Comment: @Serge _"I don't believe.."_ - this method was explicitly created to write a string to response and [resolves to `HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync()`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Results/HttpResultsHelper.cs,88fd7e4967304899)  call which basically encodes string into bytes and writes to the response.

Comment: @GuruStron I am sorry, but I mean the final result. See my comment above especially if OP uses  contentType: "application/json")

Comment: @Serge no 1) this will result in double encoding too (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75775299/2501279) for example, though just returning string would work) 2) those are controller based methods, here we are talking about Minimal APIs.

Comment: @GuruStron This is why IResult was created, to replace IActionResult. And result is the same.

Comment: @Serge `Results.Content` returns `IResult`. It is just a convenience static class to simplify creation of `IResult`, the same as `Ok`, `Json`, etc. methods on base controller.

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, this is what I mean, I am glad that you finally agree with me.

Comment: @Serge sorry, but I don't understand. I have never claimed that `Results.Content` does not return `IResult` =)

Comment: @GuruStron Ok, it is just misunderstanding. I think I understand what OP mean but the question is not correct.  it will return a json string in any case, but  I think if  json returns as a string  it will be  serialized twice and will need double deserialization too. I think JObject.Parse will do the same but am sure there is a better way. But I am sorry, it is 2am here already and I had a bad day and very tired. I will give my answer tommorrow.