# Getting plaintext response from ASP.NET Core 7 Web API endpoint

Tags: c#, blazor, http-post, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

I have a simple ASP.NET Core 7 Web API method:

```
[HttpPost("processPiece")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> ProcessPiece([FromBody] PieceModel piece)
{
    return _processingService.ProcessPiece(piece.Piece);
}
```

The `ProcessPiece` method returns a string value. It contains multiple lines.

I'm trying to display this value in a Blazor component on the UI.

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"api/Piece/processPiece", new StringContent("{\"piece\":\"" + piece + "\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The view markup is very simple for now:

```
<p>@outputValue</p>
```

I found out that `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` returns the string wrapped in extra quotes, and instead of rendering a new line it shows `"\r\n"`.

It seems the output is somehow escaped during transport or decoding.

I've looked for solutions here, but all the threads I found on the topic seem to be at least 10 years old and the provided solutions don't seem to work.

Regardless, I've tried implementing one of the suggested solutions, by switching the type the endpoint returns to plaintext:

```
[HttpPost("processPiece")]
public async Task<ActionResult<HttpResponseMessage>> ProcessPiece([FromBody] PieceModel piece)
{
     var  a =  _processingService.ProcessPiece(piece.Piece);
     var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     resp.Content = new StringContent(a, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
     return resp;
}
```

Client side:

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"api/Piece/processPiece", new StringContent("{\"piece\":\"" + piece + "\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/plaintext"));
    var a = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return a;
```

This didn't work at all. Now all I get from the endpoint is a bunch of metadata:

```
{"version":"1.1","content":{"headers":[{"key":"Content-Type","value":["text/plain; charset=utf-8"]}]},"statusCode":200,"reasonPhrase":"OK","headers":[],"trailingHeaders":[],"requestMessage":null,"isSuccessStatusCode":true}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is .NET 6 minimal API returning JSON as a string and not as JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75805720/why-is-net-6-minimal-api-returning-json-as-a-string-and-not-as-json)

Comment: _"instead of rendering a new line it shows \r\n"_ is expected in the debugger view and html mostly ignores `\r\n` . So maybe your first attempt was correct all along, just not the simple `@outputValue`.

Comment: @h-h it renders "\r\n" on the web page itself. I'm dumb, but not that dumb :) I originally wrote "\r\n" in my question to indicate this, the genius that edited my question took the quotes out.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Core does not handle `HttpResponseMessage` as a special type, so you result will be serialized to JSON (so if you return just a string it will be encoded as JSON, hence the extra quotes). Just use one of the `Content` options. For example:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessPiece([FromBody] PieceModel piece)
{
    return Content("somestring", "text/plain", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Or via `Results`/`TypedResults` (depending on the use case).

Comment: return Content(a, "text/plain", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8); <- here VS tells me Content is not recognized, and it doesn't offer to add any "using" statement. So I assume this code is from some different version of asp.net?

Comment: I tried "return Results.Content..., I get this: 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IResult' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Shaggydog this method is present in ASP.NET Core since 1.0 - [check it yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.content?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controllerbase-content(system-string-system-string-system-text-encoding)). I assume you are using it (based on tags). Do you have a [mre]? Can you post it somewhere (github for example)?